# Is there a key combination in Xcode to implement a Protocol?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, refactoring, code-generation

In Visual Studio if I define a class to implement an interface e.g.

```
class MyObject : ISerializable {}
```

I am able to right click on ISerializable, select "*Implement Interface*" from the context menu and see the appropriate methods appear in my class definition.

```
class MyObject : ISerializable {
    #region ISerializable Members
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, 
                StreamingContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Is there anything anything like this functionality available in Xcode on the Mac? I would like to be able to automatically implement Protocols in this way. Maybe with the optional methods generated but commented out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not seen that feature in Xcode.
But it seems like someone could write a new user script called "Place Implementor Defs on Clipboard" that sits inside of Scripts > Code.

You did not find this useful.

Comment: Who didn't find what useful, and why, and apropos of what?

Answer (score 22):

XCode currently does not support that kind of automation. But: an easy way to get your code bootstrapped with a protocol is to option-click the protocol name in your class declaration

```
@interface FooAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, 
                                      NSTableViewDelegate> {
```

to quickly open the .h file defining the protocol. From there, copy and paste the methods you're interested in. Those headers tend to be well-commented, which helps in determining which methods you can safely ignore.

Comment: But you are not answering the question. He is asking about a key combination for adding them to avoid doing the copy/paste.

Comment: @lagos I think Clay is answering the question. He's saying the answer is "no" and offering an alternative.

Answer (score 5):

There is not currently such a refactoring in Xcode.

If you'd like it, please file an [enhancement request](http://bugreport.apple.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread s a bit old, but I wondered the same thing and found this question.

In my case, I'm defining a property in the interface (.h) and I want to synthesize it in the implementation (.m). I also need to implement methods defined in the interface. Yes, Xcode helps as others have mentioned, but modern IDEs offer these productivity enhancements for things we do frequently. It appears that this is still not a feature in Xcode 4.3.3.  However, the feature is available in [JetBrains' AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/index.html). I'm only dabbling with the trial, but it appears to only be possible one property or method at a time, not the whole interface like Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode can help you per protocol method, lets say you have a protocol like this:

```
@protocol PosterousWebsitesDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)PosterousWebsitesLoadSuccess:(PosterousWebsites*)websites;
@end
```

in the @implementation section of your .m file you can start writing the name of the method and pressing ESC key to autocomplete the signature of the method/selector:

```
-(void)Poste (...press ESC...)
```

Xcode will autocomplete a full signature of the @protocol method, pres TAB to confirm the code.

If you are really committing to learn OSX/iOS Development, I would recommend you to read "XCode 3 Unleashed", a book that really helped me to know Xcode as deep as I know VS :)

Comment: You can even do it quicker by just writing
`- P (press ESC)` (without return type - Xcode5 will still show the correct selector).
See Development_gems from wwdc videos...

Answer (score 1):

check this plugin

https://github.com/music4kid/FastStub-Xcode

it does the thing that you are asking for and more.

Answer (score 0):

[Macrumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=6180803#post6180803) had a discussion on this too. There is a link to some apple scripts. I haven't actually tried these.